# How to split a 2D numpy array directly into numpy array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a special application dealing with numpy arrays of different lengths, I need my preferably numpy array, **not just a list**, to have the form `np.ndarray[np.ndarray[ ], np.ndarray[ ], ..., dtype=object]`. If I have given sequence, list, etc. of `numpy` arrays, I want them always to have this form. However, for a list of numpy arrays of the **same** length, e.g.,

```
np.array(*np.array([np.arange(4), np.arange(4)], dtype=object)
```

gives me `np.ndarray[np.ndarray[[]], dtype=object]` so I came up with the workaround below.

Is there any other magic option, which could be passed to `np.array()` or another method which gives the desired result more directly?

Workaround:

```
inp_arr_a = np.asarray([np.arange(4), np.arange(3)], dtype=object)
inp_arr_b = np.array([np.arange(4), np.arange(4)])

def split_to_obj_arr(arr):
    return np.delete(np.array([*arr, 'dummy'], dtype=object), -1, 0)
```

gives for `split_to_obj_arr(inp_arr_a)`

```
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

and for `split_to_obj_arr(inp_arr_b)`

```
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.array(...)` by design tries to return as high a dimensional numeric array as possible.  If the inputs are ragged it will raise a future-warning (unless you specify `object` dtype) and return the object array containing arrays.  Or with some combinations of shapes it will raise an error.

Forcing an object dtype with the `None` element and then deleting that is one way around this.  I prefer creating the `None` filled array first, and assigning the elements:

```
In [80]: def foo(alist):
    ...:     res = np.empty(len(alist), object)
    ...:     res[:] = alist
    ...:     return res
    ...: 
In [81]: foo([[],[]])
Out[81]: array([list([]), list([])], dtype=object)
In [82]: foo([np.array([]),np.array([])])
Out[82]: array([array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64)], dtype=object)
In [83]: foo([np.ones((2,3)),np.zeros((2,3))])
Out[83]: 
array([array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
In [84]: foo([np.array([2,3]),np.array([1,2])])
Out[84]: array([array([2, 3]), array([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Creating a 2d object array like this is also possible, but trickier.  It may be simpler to reshape a 1d as needed after.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed more straight. In order to get also the exmample `inp_arr_b ` above working (it's a `array([[]]))` type), line 3 tin `def foo()` should, e.g., read `res[:] = [*alist]`